# SELECT...FOR UPDATE - Will only an UPDATE release the lock?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, locking

I'm using a `SELECT ...FOR UPDATE` in a Java PreparedStatement.  I may or may not need to execute the update depending on the results of the `SELECT`.

If I execute a `rs.close();` or `pStmt.close();` *without* doing an update, will MySQL release the lock? Is there another way to release it, or do I have to execute the update?

Same question if I used Postgres, too.

Not sure if it matters, but I plan to use `rs.updateRow();` for the update.
Also, does MySQL support column-level locking?

Basically, I want to increment a counter in the selected row, but only if the row's status column is *ACTIVE*.  If it is not *ACTIVE*, then I just want to release the lock without an update so other threads/processes can read/write that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to increment a counter in the selected row, but only if the row's status column is ACTIVE. If it is not ACTIVE, then I just want to release the lock without an update so other threads/processes can read/write that row.

Don't have the `SELECT`; simply do

```
UPDATE tbl
    WHERE ...
      AND status = 'active'
```

The `UPDATE` will either change the row or do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to retrieve the value for my processing, too.  Just an `UPDATE' won't return the value or a recordset.  But, by adding that where clause I can safely execute the update every time, thereby releasing the lock.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that won't release the lock.  Only `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` will release it.

Comment: Why is the transaction taking so long that the lock matters?

Answer (score 7):

Don't know about MySQL, but in Postgresql, the lock is only valid for the duration of the current transaction, so:

- you must have started a transaction
- the lock will be released if you commit or rollback the transaction

If you don't start an explicit transaction, then the lock will be released right away.